# What does this iptables rule mean?

Tags: iptables

Reading this [article on how to configure OpenVPN](http://readwrite.com/2014/04/10/raspberry-pi-vpn-tutorial-server-secure-web-browsing), I see the following paragraph:

> Raspbian has a firewall to protect your Raspberry Pi from unknown and unexpected Internet sources. We still want the firewall to protect us from most incoming and outgoing network traffic, but we need to poke an OpenVPN-shaped hole in the firewall.

The article then suggests using this `iptables` rule to solve this problem:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.XX.X
```

with `10.8.0.0` being the default address of the VPN for the clients connected to the VPN, and `192.168.XX.X` being the IP address of the OpenVPN server on the local network.

I might be completely misunderstanding this, but I thought this rule meant "for each packet with source IP address `10.8.0.0`, change the source IP address to `192.168.XX.X` before routing it out the `eth0` interface".

If this is correct, how would this "poke an OpenVPN-shaped hole in the firewall"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: This is about routing, it has nothing to do with security.

Answer (score 2):

What the rule does is simply enable SNAT for traffice originating from an openvpn client, so that openvpn clients can use the internet connection you this system. I.e. outgoing traffic from openvpn clients are allowed through, so you could consider this a hole in the firewall. I think the author was trying to write in a humorous style, which doesn't always work...

Note that `-s 10.8.0.0/24` doesn't mean "source IP address 10.8.0.0", it means "source IP address in the 10.8.0.0/24 network", i.e. `10.8.0.*`.

Comment: `POSTROUTING` doesn't allow any traffic. It affects allowed traffic only. And `SNAT` is (probably) not only required for Internet access but for accessing any other host on the LAN.

Comment: That's what I thought. Consequently, even `10.8.0.0` is not the IP address of the VPN server, as the article states, but the VPN network ID, correct?
I think that part of the article is quite confusing tbh.

Comment: I'd say `10.8.0.0/24` is "the network", leave out the "ID" part. `10.8.0.0` *could* be the IP address of the VPN server on the VPN side, although I doubt it as `.0` is usually avoided.

Comment: `10.8.0.0` **cannot** be a host address in a `/24` network because `.0` is the network address.

Comment: @wurtel actually, the correct term is indeed "network ID" :P